# Какие стили лучше задавать по умолчанию?

Tags: css, вёрстка

При просмотре туториалов, связанных с версткой заметил, что часто перед началом работы, авторы задают какие-то стили по умолчанию, переопределяют дефолтные стили браузера. Собственно, возникло пару вопросов по этому поводу:

- Зачем это делается?
- Стили каких элементов лучше переопределить в самом начале?
- Где можно об этом почитать поподробнее и найти код? Гуггл мне не очень помог, каюсь, может плохо гугглил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Зачем это делается?

По умолчанию, в браузерах есть встроенные определения для HTML-элементов. Например, у `<body>` и `<p>` есть `margin`, у `<ul>` и `<ol>` есть `padding` и `list-style`, ну и так далее. В каждом браузере эти предустановленные значения могут быть разными, соответственно, `normalize.css` или `reset.css` нужны для того, чтобы стартовать с одинаковой базы. Различие их состоит в том, что `normalize.css` приводит все элементы к одинаковому стилю, а `reset.css` сбрасывает всё полностью в ноль. Лично мне больше нравится использовать `reset.css`, потому что, как правило, все элементы потом всё равно переопределяются и для каждого проекта формируется некое подобие UI kit. Но если вы верстаете страницу без формирования определения всех элементов, то, возможно, вам подойдет `normalize.css` — так вам не надо будет задавать отступы между параграфами и заголовками, переопределять списки и т. д.

### Стили каких элементов лучше переопределить в самом начале?

Тут всё упирается в то, какую стратегию вы выбрали :) Мой необходимый набор:

```
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

### Где можно об этом почитать поподробнее и найти код?

Хорошая [статья](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/64-about-normalize-css) на HTML-академии и на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/45296/).

Код: [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/5.0.0/normalize.css).

P.S. reset будущего будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
* {
  all: unset;
}

head {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Есть два основных подхода - reset.css и normalize.css. Остальное - в google.com

Answer (score 3):

```
html, body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Остальное - ручки)

Answer (score 3):

- Делается для того, чтобы у всех браузеров привести дефолтные стили к какому-то номиналу, и получить более ожидаемое поведение от элементов на странице и не было всевозможных "призрачных" отступов в каком-нибудь фаерфоксе, и корректного отображения в хроме(например).
- Переопределяются в основном ссылки, списки, отступы внутренние и внешние у `body`, `div'a`, поля ввода, по большому счету, все, что используется в проекте, по хорошему необходимо "обнулить".
- Гугли всевозможные `reset.css`.

---

Например, как можно видеть на скрине, в разных браузерах стили рендерятся по разному. В данном случае, `FF` добавил отступ перед тэгом `p`. Во избежание таких случаев и применяются сбросы стилей.
[image: Рендер стилей в разных браузерах]

Немного советов:

- Сброс стилей - отдельным файлом, включаемым в документ в самом начале.
- Лучше индивидуальным элементам расписывать сбросы стилей отдельно, дабы достичь максимального контроля над внешним видом страницы. Из минусов - разве что, что-нибудь забыть.
- Сброс не обязательно приводить к нулевым значениям, можно сразу указать те, что по дефолту будут использоваться в Вашем проекте.

Написанное выше является выдержкой из статьи с хабра, [отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/45296/), .

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) популярная и проверенная библиотека для нормализации стилей в разных браузерах. А дальше используйте сброс(задавать по умолчанию) стилей по вашему вкусу.

Comment: Устаревшее дно, которое ничего не решает.

Comment: http://jaydenseric.com/blog/forget-normalize-or-resets-lay-your-own-css-foundation