# Полоса слева и сверху

Tags: css, google-chrome, stripe

Заметил что в хроме появляются непонятные полосы слева и над элементом после наведения или выделения мышью. Позже выяснил, что проблема исчезает если убрать `background-color` и  `background-blend-mode`.

Но как эти свойства могут влиять? Помогите понять суть проблемы.

**PS** В Edge и Mozilla изначально отображается нормально.

```
body {
  background-image: url(img/wall.jpg);
  background-color: white;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

[image: Пример]

Comment: А зачем вам `background-color: white;` если у вас фон картинка?

Comment: Чтобы сделать контент более читабельным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы столкнулись с стилями которые Chrome устанавливает для различных элементов по умолчанию, исправляется это переопределением этих самых стилей.

Что бы не делать это вручную можете использовать уже готовые решения reset.css и normalize.css.

Более подробный ответ дан в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/625576/219390) комментарии.